# Convert string to Int

Tags: java, swing

I have a setText that displays a number, I have converted this string to an int. But I am unsure on how to convert a string with a decimal (16.50).

```
JCheckBox sesh2 = new JCheckBox ("Morning (8am - 12pm)"); sPanel.add(sesh2);
JTextField tSesh2 = new JTextField("0"); sPanel.add(tSesh2);
sesh2.addActionListener(e3->{
    if (sesh2.isSelected())
        tSesh2.setText("16.50");
});
```

Also:

```
int total2 = Integer.parseInt(tSesh2.getText());
```

How can I convert decimal numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` and `Integer` are whole number values. You need to use `double` or `Double.

```
double total2 = Double.parseDouble(tSes2.gettext());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know whether the input represents a integer or a floating point number, then you can use `NumberFormat`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)

```
java> java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance().parse("123");
java.lang.Long res2 = 123
java> java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance().parse("123.45");
java.lang.Double res3 = 123.45
```